# Rails generate link with array parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, link-to

Need an advice how to generate list of links with array of paramenter

```
/controller/action/id?pid1=1001&vid1=1002&pid2=2001&vid2=2002
/controller/action/id?pid1=1001&vid1=1002&pid2=2001&vid2=2003
/controller/action/id?pid1=7001&vid1=7002&pid2=2001&vid2=2003
```

Where **pid** is id of filter type, and **vid** is id of filter value.

Comment: how does your "array of parameters" look like?

Comment: i need link like in question, but how to generate it by using method link_to and params. And while render a page i need check pid with id 1001 or 2001 used in url already.

Comment: right no problem, but how does your params look? I'll give a basic answer and craft it according to what you let me know

Answer (score 0):

What I assume you have is parameters in an array like so

`params_array = ["a","b","c", "d"]` where the first parameter is pid1, second is vid1, third is pid2, fourth is vid2

if this is the setup, then try this:

`link_to "this is some link text", some_path, :pid1 => params_array[0], :vid2 => params_array[1] %>`

etc... there are better ways to do this with loops/etc. to format the params better, but in order to do so I need to know how your original params are like.

EDIT: Again, I'm really not sure how your data is formatted so for me to be able to give you any more useful help, you'll need to expand the question with more data.

What I can tell you though is that if you wanted to have a loop to go through and merge the params, you could do so like this:

`pid_parameters = params_array.each_with_index.map {|e, i| {"#{i%2==0 ? "pid" : "vid"}#{i+1}" => a[i]}}`

and then `link_to "this is some link text", some_path, pid_parameters` which will produce something like:

`/controller/action/id?pid1=1001&vid2=1002&pid3=2001&vid4=2002`

again, give some more information for this to be relevant. Thanks